# Search through an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array containing `7 integers {1,5,2,3,6,4,7}`. Each of these integers represents prioritization for 7 hospitals (h1-h7). `Element 1 in the array is h1, element 2 is h2` and so on. I want to search through this array and find integer 1 and if that hospital fulfills some conditions then I want to return that hospital (i.e. h1), otherwise check prio 2 and check if that hospital fullfills some conditions. `If yes return h2`, and if not continue until the array has been checked. How would I do this in Java code?

Comment: what are the fulfillment conditions??

Comment: @Kojotak in an array as i understand it

Comment: you should take a look at Arrays#binarySearch. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29

Comment: In my understanding the array keeps just the hospital indexes...

Comment: @Boopathi - The condition is if the hospital is full.

Comment: `(for idx:new int[]{1,5,2,3,6,4,7}){ Hospital h = getHospital(idx); if(h.isFull()){ return h;} }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefere to use a collection of hospital objects instead of the array, but if this is not what you want you may use this:

```
int highestPriorityHospitalIndex(int[] a)
{
    for (int priority = 1; priority <= 7; priority++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == priority && checkConditions(i))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
return -1;
}
```